# Request size is too large error while ingesting to cosmos DB

Tags: r, azure-cosmosdb, sparkr

I'm trying to ingest data to CosmosDB from `SparkR`.I have my data in the form of dataframe.I tested with sample dataset and the data is getting ingested.But when I try to ingest a large amount of data, I'm getting an error like

> {"Errors":["Request size is too large"]}

I made sure that the dataframe size doesn't exceed 2MB I came to know that the maximum limit of document size to be 2MB in CosmosDB from [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143986/azure-documentdb-storage-limits-what-exactly-do-they-mean). Please guide me on where I should correct.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the details like some code which cause this error?

Comment: con <- mongo(collection = "sampler", url = mongo_url)
**con$insert(output_rich_dataset)** This is where the error occurs

Comment: What's the mongo driver for R you used? Is it [`mongosoup/rmongodb`](https://github.com/dselivanov/rmongodb) or `RMongo`? However, according to the error information, I think it was sure that the document serialized from `output_rich_dataset` is too large over 2MB, please serialize it and check the serialized json size whether exceeded the limits.

Comment: I'm using mongolite package for data ingestion.I used object.size() method to get the size of dataframe.Is there any better method to get the size ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on using [`mongolite`](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite) driver you used now, I reviewed the source code of the driver which used [`jsonlite`](https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite) to serialize a R object to json. So you can check the size of the json document which you want to insert into Azure CosmosDB as the code below.

```
library(jsonlite)
# Serialize a R object to json using jsonlite
json <- serializeJSON(output_rich_dataset)
# Count the byte size of the json document using `nchar` method
size <- nchar(json)
print(size)
```

Hope it helps.