# How to fetch All records from azure cosmos db using query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to fetch more than 100 records from azure-cosmos DB using select query.

I am writing a stored procedure and using a select query to fetch the record.

This is my stored procedure -

```
function getall(){
 var context = getContext();
  var response = context.getResponse();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

  var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM c';

  collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, {pageSize:-1 },
    function(err, documents) {
      response.setBody(response.getBody() + JSON.stringify(documents));
    }
  );
}
```

Initially, It was working with less amount of data in database.

But, with large amount of data,
   The stored procedure is throwing this exception -

> Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error:
>   Resulting message would be too large because of "Body". Return from
>   script with current message and use continuation token to call the
>   script again or modify your script. Stack trace: Error: Resulting
>   message would be too large because of "Body". Return from script with
>   current message and use continuation token to call the script again or
>   modify your script.

Comment: Would you please tell me the specific amount of your large amount of data?

Comment: We got issue after 700 records and each record's max size is upto 1 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document DB imposes limits on Response page size.
This link summarizes some of those limits:
[Azure DocumentDb Storage Limits - what exactly do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143986/azure-documentdb-storage-limits-what-exactly-do-they-mean)

You can paginate your data using continuation tokens. The Document Db sdk supports reading paginated data seamlessly.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-paging-support-with-top-and-more-query-improvements/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .NET sdk to retrieve the data returned by your stored procedure? If so, take advantage of the .HasMoreResults. It automatically get the allowed size data results thus not showing the error you posted. Loop through it until there's no more fetched results.

http://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/08/19/paging-through-query-results-in-azure-documentdb/