# Querying large collections in cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We currently have a very large collection in our document DB.
We want to be able to filter the collection based on some fields in the documents in the collection.

When I perform this query via the portal it takes a really long time because there is so much data.
When I perform this query via a function app, it cuts out after five minutes due to a time-out.

What is the best way to perform this search?
Is it possible to perform this search via Application Insights or some sort?
I am aware that the query itself can take a long time but it shouldn't be blocking. Querying via the portal blocks all other actions.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: As written, this question is unclear and too broad: We have no idea what data you're querying, the query you're trying to execute, your indexes, how much data you're trying to return, if you're using DocumentDB SQL API or MongoDB API, your definition of "large collection" -
 a 10GB single-partition collection? A multi-partition collection with partition key? Basically, we only know you are hitting a timeout situation. So there is no way to give you any advice without more detail. Please edit your question to be much more specific, including the details I called out.

Comment: @GauravMantri - honestly, with the dearth of information provided in the question, I don't think a tool recommendation is going to matter.

Comment: @DavidMakogon...agreed and deleted my comment. In all fairness, the way I read this question is that OP knows that the query is a time consuming query yet wanted a non-blocking way of executing it. This is why I made tool recommendation.

Comment: Any updates ? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong your answer is getting me to the right solution. I am going to try and implement your advise today. If it doesn't work, I shall notify you here.

Comment: @Homewrecker Sure.

Comment: In addition to tools mentioned by @JayGong you should really consider your data model as DocumentDB is not really intended for unindexed heavy scans. For example, consider data modelling tips mentioned in [this presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P468).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, what you need to know is that Document DB imposes limits on `Response page size`. This link summarizes some of those limits: [Azure DocumentDb Storage Limits - what exactly do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143986/azure-documentdb-storage-limits-what-exactly-do-they-mean)

Secondly, if you want to query large data from Document DB, you have to consider the query performance issue, please refer to this article:[Tuning query performance with Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics).

By looking at the [Document DB REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/query-documents), you can observe several important parameters which has a significant impact on query operations : `x-ms-max-item-count, x-ms-continuation.`

Azure portal doesn't automatically help you optimize your SQL so you need to handle this in the sdk or rest api.

You could set value of [Max Item Count](http://Doesn't%20automatically%20help%20you%20optimize%20your%20SQL) and paginate your data using `continuation tokens`. The Document Db sdk supports reading paginated data seamlessly. You could refer to the snippet of python code as below:

```
q = client.QueryDocuments(collection_link, query, {'maxItemCount':10})
results_1 = q._fetch_function({'maxItemCount':10})
#this is a string representing a JSON object
token = results_1[1]['x-ms-continuation']
results_2 = q._fetch_function({'maxItemCount':10,'continuation':token})
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

CosmosDB is extremely predictable with very low latency, but when it comes to returning big resultset it is really cumbersome to work with unless you can spend alot of $$$ on it. One way for you could be to use CosmosDb for your domainmodel, and then you use the ChangeFeed to handle the readmodels you need, in my case Im having my domainmodel where all insert/updates are handled. And then as a secondary step it start up a ChangeFeedProcessing that take the resultset, and see if that model need one or more readmodels, and if it does, what storage does it need, at the moment I can persist and update the readmodel to either TableStorage or Azure Search or both. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed

Comment: I've also found cosmos db not to be great at aggregations. Is this your experience as well? I mean there are the known issues, like only being able to sum on one column at a time unless you are in a single partition, but even given those constraints the performance is less than I would hope for.